# How to use <merge> with view binding?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I can't get layouts with merge root tag to work with view binding. Is it possible?

include_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_test"
        layout="@layout/merge_layout"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

merge_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/include_test">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A Title"/>
</merge>
```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  val binding = IncludeLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
  setContentView(binding.root)
  binding.includeTest.title.text = "New Title"
}
```

Runtime exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: includeTest`

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52343338/2855059

Comment: this might be a duplicated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659241/3763032 @ham

Comment: @mochadwi this doesn't work with merge tags.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/exploring-viewbinding-in-depth-598925821e41) it's possible

for example :

my_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include
    layout="@layout/my_include_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

my_include_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</merge>
```

MyFragment.kt

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
 private val binding: MyFragmentBinding get() = _binding!!
 private var _binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
 private val myIncludeLayoutBinding: MyIncludeLayoutBinding get() = _myIncludeLayoutBinding!!
 private var _myIncludeLayoutBinding: MyIncludeLayoutBinding? = null

 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    _binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    _myIncludeLayoutBinding = MyIncludeLayoutBinding.bind(binding.root)
    return binding.root
 }

 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    myIncludeLayoutBinding.button.setOnClickListener{
        
    }
 }

 override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
    _myIncludeLayoutBinding = null
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It isn't supported.

See official docs here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

Edit:
Whoops, those docs talk about data-binding, not view-bindings.

Comment: The linked page talks about _data_ binding not being supported in this case, but the question is about _view_ binding.

Comment: it talks about not supporting <inlcude> as a direct child of merge. But data-binding does support include of <merge> layout like in author's example